# MX record remain the same after changing

Tags: email, mx-record, dns-zone

I accidentally change the MX record and change it back, but even when i change back, when i send the email to the account that with the domain name, it show the recipient not found, and show me

```
Final-Recipient: rfc822; jasonchan@joycular.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.1.1
Remote-MTA: dns; smtp.asia.secureserver.net. (182.50.144.66, the server for
 the domain xxx.com.)
```

my MX record is

```
MX  @   alt1.aspmx.l.google.com (Priority: 5)   
MX  @   alt2.aspmx.l.google.com (Priority: 5)   
MX  @   aspmx.l.google.com (Priority: 1)    
MX  @   aspmx2.googlemail.com (Priority: 10)    
MX  @   aspmx3.googlemail.com (Priority: 10)
```

the domain is buy with google, what wrong with my setting?

Comment: How long ago did you change it? It can take up to 48 hours to propagate changed DNS records.

Comment: Also try purging your DNS cache.

Comment: Did you change the zone serial number? If so, when and how?

Comment: Not finding the MX record and Recipient Not Found aren't the same thing. Does the recipient mailbox actually exist? If `joycular.com` is your domain name then your MX record appears to be fine.

Answer (score 1):

At the heart of DNS is caching (Time To Live). What will have happened is the host that is sending the email has already cached the (incorrect) DNS records for your domain, and will not re-fetch them until the TTL has expired.

The only workaround for this is to flush the DNS cache on the sending server, which you can only do if it is a server that you control.